# Javascript: Manipulating a list of lists

Tags: javascript, pattern-matching, nested-lists

Let's say I have the following:

```js
const tasks = [
    ["Task 1", (() => console.log(123))],
    ["Task 2", (() =>console.log(456))]
];
```

Is there a way of expressing this:

```js
tasks.forEach( t => {
        console.log(`running ! ${t[0]}`);
        t[1]();
    }
)
```

in a form resembling this:

```js
tasks.forEach( (taskName, f) => {
        console.log(`running ! ${f}`);
        f();
    }
)
```

Sadly with the `(x, i)` syntax, `i` gives me the index of the items in the list and I cannot get it to refer to the function. I also tried using the `[..., ]` syntax without luck

Comment: You can destructure your parameter: `tasks.forEach( (taskName, f)` -> `tasks.forEach( ([taskName, f])`

Comment: hmmm i tried that and got: `TypeError: [object Array] is not a function`

Comment: [I cannot reproduce that error](https://jsbin.com/duvayar/edit?js,console)

Comment: ah yeah that version works. thanks.

Comment: I copied your code, and replaced the section I pointed out. Should have worked for you as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Can destructure the element as you iterate though the array...

```
tasks.forEach( ([taskName, f]) => {
        console.log(`running ! ${taskName}`);
        f();
    }
)
```

returns...

```
"running ! Task 1"
123
"running ! Task 2"
456
```